# State which contain space and newline changed doesn't case re-render

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

What I want to do is achieve a code beautify function by using textarea, here is my code:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: '{"city": "NY"}'
        }
    }
    onClick = () => {
        var beautifyResult = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(this.state.value), null, 4);
        console.log(beautifyResult);
        this.setState({
            value: beautifyResult
        })
    }
    render = () => {
        return (
            <div className="ui form">
                <button onClick={this.onClick}>beautify</button>
                <textarea defaultValue={this.state.value}></textarea>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

When the use click the beautify button on page, the json string be beautify by using `JSON.stringify`. In the `onClick` handler I check the `beautifyResult` is beautified as I want:

```
{
    "city": "NY"
}
```

But the content in the textarea doesn't change, I think React compare state change with ignoring space and newline. So how can I solve this problem? Or hack it?

Comment: `value` begins as being equal to a string - then you stringify, but it's already a string.. then parse as JSON, at which point it's no longer a string, and JSON is a data format.. so I think perhaps you'd have more luck keeping it as a string? I'm not entirely sure though, only answering since no one else has responded.

Comment: He is just using `JSON.stringify` for its formatting options. 

Have you tried using `this.replaceState`? Also there is `this.forceUpdate()`. Take a look here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#replacestate

Answer (score 0):

The textarea will not update `onClick` because `defaultValue` only works on **initial load**. (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#default-value)

One way to solve this, is to use ref's to update the contents of the textarea onClick.

e.g.

```
  onClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let beautifyResult = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(this._textArea.value), null, 4);
    this._textArea.value = beautifyResult;
    this.setState({
        value: beautifyResult
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ui form">
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Beautify</button>
        <textarea 
          ref={t => this._textArea = t} 
          defaultValue={this.state.value}>
        </textarea>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

http://codepen.io/jzmmm/pen/pbVavN?editors=0010